# What does "taking in its own washing" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"The provincial town still belonged essentially to the economy and society of the countryside. It lived by battening on the surrounding peasantry and (with relatively few exceptions) **by very little else except taking in its own washing."**

What is meant by the phrase "taking in its own washing" and what specifically "it" refers to, peasantry or townspeople?

It's taken from Age Of Revolution 1789-1848 by Eric Hobsbawm

Comment: What's the source of this quote? Please [edit] it into your post.

Comment: Take a look at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167412/what-is-the-meaning-of-taking-in-each-others-washing.  This is kind of the same-but-opposite.  If "taking in someone else's washing" is doing someone else's chores for them, then "taking in your own washing" means you are self sufficient.

Comment: It means people provide services for each other, but there is no exportable product, no growth industry, no nett gain.